# Qt 5 - QWidget in Qt Quick 2

Tags: qt5

I thought of using custom defined QWidget inherited from QTableWidget or QTableWidget directly in QML (Qt Quick 2). I tried some prototype and find it's not possible to embed QWidget in Qt Quick 2 as specified in the link [Qt5. Embed QWidget object in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml).

I'm able to embed QWidget using Qt Quick 1.1 by inheriting from QDeclarativeItem but I want to achieve the same in Qt Quick 2

Do I know is there any possible way of embedding QWidget to Qt Quick 2? (May be to work by doing some workaround)

Comment: Any other way of embedding QTableWidget in QML (Qt Quick 2) is also ok...

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily embed QWidgets inside QtQuick2 scenes. Try instead using Qt Quick Controls (included with 5.1), which feature a [TableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html).