# Embed QWidget object in Qt Quick 2

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

8 months ago here was such a question - how to embed a qwidget-based object into QML,http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/declarative-cppextensions-qwidgets.html [Qt5. Embed QWidget object in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml). Has the situation changed? Or for some complex applications, using own reimplemented paintEvent, we can use only classic Qt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt5. Embed QWidget object in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml)

Comment: The original question does have answers that explain how to embed QWidgets inside Qt Quick 2 scenes. This question is thus merely a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

`QQuickPaintedItem` can be used for drawing with `QPainter` API.

In the code below I tried to wrap `QCalendarWidget` into `QQuickPaintedItem`. It renders correctly, but doesn't process input events:

.h:

```
class CalendarControl : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CalendarControl(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    virtual ~CalendarControl();

    void paint(QPainter *painter);
…
protected:
    QCalendarWidget *calendar_;
}
```

.cpp:

```
CalendarControl::CalendarControl(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
    , calendar_(NULL)
{
    setOpaquePainting(true);
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);

    calendar_ = new QCalendarWidget;

    // Calendar will draw partially if update is called right here
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(update()));
}

void CalendarControl::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    calendar_->render(painter, QPoint(), QRegion(),
        QCalendarWidget::DrawWindowBackground | QCalendarWidget::DrawChildren);
}
```

To catch mouse events, override

```
void hoverEnterEvent(QHoverEvent *event);
void hoverLeaveEvent(QHoverEvent *event);
void hoverMoveEvent(QHoverEvent *event);
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event);
```

I weren't able to pass them to `QCalendarWidget` though, it ignores them. But when creating a wrapper for custom `QWidget`, you can probably pass these events directly to it.