# Opening Qt window from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have created a C++ Qt class, inheriting from QWidget. I have also created a QML file, which runs as my main, and I want in some point of the program to open another separated window containing this widget.

The point is to draw line graphs in QML, and I don't quite understand how to do it.

Comment: So are you trying to display a widget, or are you trying to draw line graphics? These are completely separate concepts, so you should probably edit the question to make it clearer... Is opening a separate window the key point here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at this question and its answers: [Qt5. Embed QWidget object in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml)

You got into [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/205208). You do not need to embed `QWidget` to your QtQuick/QML application. *(I hope)* You can easily deal with your task using only QML. For example, there is [Canvas Element](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) that can help you to organize drawing. Take a look at [tutorial related to Canvas in QmlBook](http://qmlbook.github.io/ch07/index.html).

Hope this helps!