# Is it possible to wrapper a QWidget as QT quick control?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

We have a lot of traditional qt controls (inherit `QWidget` class)。Some of these controls are just override the `QWidget::paint()` method, other widgets are combination of basic controls (eg. button, label, ...).

I'm investigate to switch our product to use QT quick.

**So, Is there an easy way to wrapper a QWidget as QT quick control?**

And I'm aware that qt quick control can be embedded in `QWidget` via `QQuickView`

Comment: Does the `QQuickPaintedItem` fit with its `QQuickPaintedItem::paint()`?

Comment: Afaik there is not.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13028279/2245646