# how can I put a splashscreen on my project using EGFLS in qt

Tags: c++, qt, embedded, qml, splash-screen

I am developing a user interface with qt/QML and I need to show a splashscreen image at the begininning of the application.
I'm running the application on a device with a iMX6 microprocessor.
I used the library QtSplashscreen but it gives me this error: EGLFS: openGL windows cannot be mixed with others.

I know that it cannot open 2 windows simultaneously, can somebody help?

Comment: Where do you find the library `QtSplashScreen`? Can't you implement the splash screen as a normal qml file?

Comment: Please specify the version of Qt you are using.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.8

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, see this [question](http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-troubleshooting.html#ts-11):

> OpenGL and Qt Quick 2 applications can only have one fullscreen window existing at a time. Trying to create another OpenGL window, or trying to mix an OpenGL window with a raster one will display the above message and abort the application.

QSplashScreen use another window to show the splash view. So, this is not a direct solution. You can embed your QWidget inside a QQuickItem to use it as  QtQuick2 control components.

Another, and faster solution is to use a QML component and load it with a [Loader](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-loader.html). You can take a look in the Qt Examples Repository, this [file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-heartrate-game-qml-splashscreen-qml.html) is a good example.

Here we go with an easy example;

```
Loader {
    id: splashLoader
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "SplashScreen.qml"
    asynchronous: false
    visible: true

    onStatusChanged: {
        if (status === Loader.Ready) {
            appLoader.setSource("App.qml");
        }
    }
}

Connections {
    target: splashLoader.item
    onReadyToGo: {
        appLoader.visible = true
        appLoader.item.init()
        splashLoader.visible = false
        splashLoader.setSource("")
        appLoader.item.forceActiveFocus();
    }
}

Loader {
    id: appLoader
    anchors.fill: parent
    visible: false
    asynchronous: true
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (status === Loader.Ready)
            splashLoader.item.appReady()
        if (status === Loader.Error)
            splashLoader.item.errorInLoadingApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you embed a QWidget in a QQuickItem? Do you have an example for that too?

Comment: As of my knowledge, you can't mix QWidget into QQuick2. You can do it the other way around, though... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014415/qt5-embed-qwidget-object-in-qml - of course that holds only, if Qt5 is used.